# Box Muller Transform - Proving that Z is Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation, sampling

I'm studying the Box Muller transform and I cannot see how Z0 and Z1 represent standard normal distributions. I've looked at the wikipedia page for the box-muller function but they don't seem to have a proof that shows Z0,1 are normally distributed. Does anyone have any ideas about how to go about proving this?

$$Z_2 = R \cos(\Theta) = \sqrt{-2 \ln U_1} \cos(2 \pi U_2).
$$
$$Z_1 = R \sin(\Theta) = \sqrt{-2 \ln U_1} \sin(2 \pi U_2).
$$
$$ \text{where } U_1,U_2\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)
$$

Comment: A simple way is to start from the identity $Z_1+\mathrm iZ_2=R\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\Theta}$ and to check that $R$ and $\Theta$ so defined are independent with the suitable distributions. The fact that $\Theta$ is uniform on $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ is direct. As regards $R$, one can compute $P(R\geqslant r)=P(Z_1^2+Z_2^2\geqslant r^2)=\mathrm e^{-r^2/2}=P(\sqrt{-2\ln U}\geqslant r)$, to identify the distribution of $R$.

Comment: Today someone posted this question again.  I think I answered it here several years ago.